# Question on the existence of group subrepresentations.

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

Suppose $\pi:G\rightarrow GL(V)$ is a group representation and $W\subseteq V$ is a $\pi$ invariant subspace i.e., $\forall g \in G, \pi(g)(W)\subseteq W$.

A subrepresentation is defined $\pi_2:G\rightarrow GL(w)$ where $\pi_2(g)=\pi(g)|_{w}$.

However, I don't get how $\pi(g)|_{w}$ is an automorphism on W. If $W$ was finite dimensional then injectivity would imply surjectivity. But what if $W$ was infinite dimensional? How do we show that $\pi(g)|_{w}$ is surjective in that case?

Comment: $\pi(g)|_W$ has the inverse $\pi(g^{-1})|_W$.

Comment: oh right for all $g\in G$. Thanks

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown If you want to throw that up as an answer I’d happily +1